# Search for matching results in the same table by multiple substrings of one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table of brands.
I want to search in this table of brands, in order to find misspelled duplicate brands.
So for example... I have a row for the brand Coca Cola and a row of brand Coca Colla.
They both have a relation to multiple products, but they need to get merged to one single brand.

My idea is to create a `SELECT` statement in order to search for all matching brands based on a single manual input: The number of characters.
So.. for example I use the Number 4 (4 characters).

**First:** I remove the whitespace in the brand *CocaCola*
**Second:** I make it lowercase *cocacola*
**Third:** I want to split the string in substrings of 4 characters by iterating each index of the string. So you get the result like this: **coca ocac caco acol cola**.

How can I achieve something like this? Or is there perhaps another solution to find matching values?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for are called *n-grams*, specifically 4-grams because you want four characters.

For better or worse, Postgres almost does exactly what you want through [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.6).  The only issue is that this provides **tri**-gram support rather than 4-gram support.

In practice, trigrams have proven very useful for text search and similarity matching.  I would suggest that you look into the capabilities of this module, because it probably does pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't know the existance of these functions! I will try it out